# Update multiple column and row using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to update multiple column value on condition, but it's updating only single column. I'm not able to figure out why it's not updating all columns.

This is my SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MIC_UpdateIdeaInline] 
(
@UpdatedBy int,
@UpdatedOn Datetime,
@UpdateRecords [UpdateIdeaInline] READONLY
)
as
BEGIN
UPDATE MI 
        SET MI.IsPortalShare= CASE WHEN ColoumnName = 'IsPortalShare' THEN CAST(ur.ColValue as BIT) ELSE IsPortalShare END
        ,MI.Validity= CASE WHEN ColoumnName = 'Validity' THEN CAST(ur.ColValue as BIT) ELSE Validity END
        ,MI.DeadLine= CASE WHEN ColoumnName = 'DeadLine' THEN CAST(ur.ColValue as datetime) ELSE DeadLine END
        ,MI.UpdatedBy=@UpdatedBy, MI.UpdatedOn=@UpdatedOn
from [MIC_Idea] MI
Join @UpdateRecords ur ON MI.Id=ur.IdeaId 
SELECT 1       
END
```

These are my parameter while calling SP.

```
declare @p3 dbo.UpdateIdeaInline
insert into @p3 values(N'15',N'Validity',N'1')
insert into @p3 values(N'15',N'DeadLine',N'15-Jun-2017')
insert into @p3 values(N'14',N'Validity',N'0')
insert into @p3 values(N'14',N'DeadLine',N'15-Jun-2017')

exec MIC_UpdateIdeaInline @UpdatedBy=1,@UpdatedOn='2017-06-06 21:45:19.863',@UpdateRecords=@p3
go
```

**UpdateIdeaInline** is table type. It's first column contain

- Id
- ColumnName
- ColumnValue

  As You can see I want to update Column (validity and DeadLine) for same ids 14 and 15. But it's only updating validity column.

Comment: what are the columnames and colvalues for the ids 14 and 15 in your table type @UpdateRecords? columname might not be 'deadline' probably.

Comment: @Coder1991: I'm passing columnName and columnValue to which I want to update in MIC_Idea table

Comment: In the script that you have posted in your question, you have used a case when where in you are checking 'CASE WHEN ColoumnName = 'DeadLine''. Is the 'DeadLine' value available for the ids 14 and 15?

Comment: @Coder1991: yes. you can see from my exec SP paramter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your update is in single atomic transaction. Update statement updates the table twice, because ID is duplicated in UpdateRecords table. So on the second update it cannot read the value updated by the first update.

Example:
You have values 10 and 15.

Now you issue a single UPDATE joining with UpdateRecord table which has two identical IDs, but each ID for different column.

E.g. UpdateRecord has
'Col1', 30
'Col2', 40

After first update:

10-->30  (pending)

15-->15  (pending)

After second update:

10-->10  (pending)

15-->40  (pending)

After transaction is committed:

10-->10

15-->40

Comment: Got it. But is there other way to update multiple column

Comment: You should transpose UpdateRecord table, so each unique ID has all columns (see PIVOT/UNPIVOT), or you should issue multiple UPDATE statements, one per column.

Comment: Those multiple UPDATE statements can be organised in WHILE loop, so it would be ONE update, but executed multiple times. I.e. you should iterate through each Column. If you have 10 columns, then WHILE loop will have 10 iterations, regardless of the number of rows in UpdateRecord table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used `CURSOR` and now it's working.

Comment: np. any chance to mark the question as answered? ;)